# Pig Map reduce failing with permission denied

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I tried to enable history server using the link, I could do it only till hdfs dis -mkdir -p /app-logs as this was failing and I could not proceed.

Now when I run the pig script which is creating map reduce it is failing with below error. Any idea?
also when I say ls -l /mr-history/ it says no such file or directory.

Caused by:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: **Permission
>   denied:** user=mapred, access=READ,
>   inode="/mr-history/tmp/hdfs/job_1459806783854_0001-1459807556718-hdfs-PigLatin%3ADefaultJobName-1459807582179-1-1-SUCCEEDED-default-1459807564263.jhist":hdfs:hdfs:-rwxrwx---at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)

Answer (score 0):

You must be executing your command with OS-user `mapred` who has only read permission on the file/directory

> Permission denied: user=**mapred**, access=**READ**

You should try with `hdfs` user since it hase read/write access

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mapred, access=READ, inode="/mr-history/tmp/hdfs/job_1459806783854_0001-1459807556718-hdfs-PigLatin%3ADefaultJobName-1459807582179-1-1-SUCCEEDED-default-1459807564263.jhist":**hdfs**:hdfs:-**rwxrwx**---at

You can also *chmod* of file/directory for other users if you have sudo/root privilege on the hdfs node.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer. I was running it with hdfs user only but I believe map reduce job is always being kicked off by Mapred user and that's the reason it failed , I gave the permission to the user and it is working fine now.